# Problem displaying three functions with SphericalPlot3D and Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This time I try to create a menu that shows different atomic oritals, using `Manipulate`, but when I run the notebook the fpx and fpy functions are not shown.

Will any of you know what I'm doing wrong?

```
fs[theta_, phi_] := 1/Sqrt[2]*1/Sqrt[2*Pi];
fpx[theta_, phi_] := Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Cos[phi]/Sqrt[Pi];
fpy[theta_, phi_] := Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Sin[phi]/Sqrt[Pi];

Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[f[theta_, phi_], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Opacity[0.2]]}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium], Style[z, Medium]},
  Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.1], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  Boxed -> False],
 {f, {fs, fpx, fpy}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image: :(]

Comment: Remove underscores from: `SphericalPlot3D[f[theta_, phi_]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f[theta, phi]` instead of `f[theta_, phi_]`, because the [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)  pattern (`_`) is used only by [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) or [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) on the definition.

Also, well-indented code is easier to read, and therefore easier to debug.

```
SetOptions[
    SphericalPlot3D
    , Mesh -> 50
    , Boxed -> False
    , PlotRange -> All
    , PlotStyle -> { Blue, Directive[Opacity[0.2]] }
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , AxesLabel -> { Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium], Style[z, Medium] }
    , MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.1]
    , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
];

Manipulate[
    SphericalPlot3D[
        f[theta, phi]
        , {theta, 0, Pi}
        , {phi, 0, 2*Pi}
    ]
    , {
        f
        , {fs, fpx, fpy}
        , ControlType -> PopupMenu
    }
]
```

[image]